# How to modify reveal.js slide settings in a ipython/jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, jupyter

I'm writing `reveal.js` slides using the jupyter/iPython notebook. I would like to change some of the default settings is an easy way. Things I already managed (in case it helps someone)

### 1. Change the theme

Change the theme by adding a raw cell containing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/css/theme/sky.css" id="theme">
```

### 2. Changing the `reveal.js` configuration

The problem with `nbconvert` is that it loads `reveal.js` after all the cell syntax, so just adding the `<script>Reveal.configure(...)</script>` in the same way doesn't work (`Reveal` will still be unknown). The solution is to make sure the code is executed after the document has loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    Reveal.configure({
        transition: 'convex' // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom
    })
});    
</script>
```

### 3. Changing other things

This is where I fail:

**How can I set the behavior of fragments, or the background of a specific slide?**

Comment: where are you adding the script(which change the transition) mentioned in the second ?

Comment: You paste it in a cell and make it of type "Raw NBConvert". But step 2 does not work with new Jupyter version 4.2.1 for me.

Comment: In 2022 1 and 2 no longer work (and it was impressively hard to find a modern answer, so I'm posting this note here -- this answer still ranks high in search). Instead, you probably want the `SlidesExporter.reveal_transition` and `SlidesExporter.reveal_theme` settings. Example: to remove the default fade, edit `~/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py` to add the following line: `c.SlidesExporter.reveal_transition = 'none'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this is a little bit late:

Although some of them do not work, but I found another post from the same blog mention above: "Customizing your IPython slides", might be what you are asking for .

the custom.css still works for me (with Jupyter 4 and Revealjs 3.0.0). just put the custom.css file in the same directory where your .html is in.

to change font (remember the '.reveal'):

```
.reveal p {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
color: #2d28cc;
}
```

to add a background (but the background colors from the theme will disappear, maybe need more css tweak):

```
body {
  background: url(logo.png)
  no-repeat
  left center;
padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
}
```

to add things to specific slides, I would use a custom div, e.g.:

```
div.footer {
font-size:14pt;
font-style: italic;
color: #4aaeee;
text-align: center
}
```

then add this to the jupyter cell:

```
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

Comment: That link doesn't work any more. Can you find any other link? Or was there a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the general theme or the transitions.

The basic idea is to create a config file `slides_config.py` somewhere (i.e. in the same folder as your slides):

```
c = get_config()
c.Exporter.template_file = 'default_transition'
```

Then, you create another template file `default_transition.tpl`:

```
{%- extends 'slides_reveal.tpl' -%}


{% block body %}

{{ super() }}

<script>

Reveal.initialize({

    // Display controls in the bottom right corner
    //controls: true,

    // Display a presentation progress bar
    //progress: true,

    // Push each slide change to the browser history
    //history: false,

    // Enable keyboard shortcuts for navigation
    //keyboard: true,

    // Enable touch events for navigation
    //touch: true,

    // Enable the slide overview mode
    //overview: true,

    // Vertical centering of slides
    //center: true,

    // Loop the presentation
    //loop: false,

    // Change the presentation direction to be RTL
    //rtl: false,

    // Number of milliseconds between automatically proceeding to the
    // next slide, disabled when set to 0, this value can be overwritten
    // by using a data-autoslide attribute on your slides
    //autoSlide: 0,

    // Enable slide navigation via mouse wheel
    //mouseWheel: false,

    // Transition style
    transition: 'concave', // default/cube/page/concave/zoom/linear/fade/none

    // Transition speed
    //transitionSpeed: 'default', // default/fast/slow

    // Transition style for full page backgrounds
    //backgroundTransition: 'default', // default/linear/none

    // Theme
    theme: 'sky' // available themes are in /css/theme

});

</script>

{% endblock body %}
```

Additionally, when you want to change some CSS details, you can create a custom CSS file `custom.css` and add your desired content in there.

The custom CSS file gets loaded automatically.

Comment: The blog you have referenced is very old. Now it convert using the command *Jupyter nbconvert slideshow.ipynb --to slides --post serve* I still do not know how to put logo on each slide.

Comment: indeed, the solution given in the blog does not work anymore and it is difficult to find another solution to change the presentation's default parameters